# Carbon: return a timestamp based on input date string AND timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime, php-carbon

Take someone from Europe/Paris (+02:00) for example.

I want to build a function where I pass in a date and time string ('2016-10-6 06:00 PM') and my time zone identifier ('Europe/Paris'). I want to return the corresponding GMT timestamp.

```
getTimestamp('2016-10-6 06:00 PM', 'Europe/Paris')
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
public function getTimestamp($string, $time_zone)
{
    $c = Carbon::parse($string);
    $c->timezone = new DateTimeZone($time_zone);
    return $c->timestamp;
}
```

**Problem**

If a pass a date and time of `2016-10-06 06:00 PM` and a time zone of `Europe/Paris` I get back a UTC timestamp that corresponds to 2016-10-06 06:00 PM GMT.

It should be returning a time of 04:00 GMT because Europe/Paris is two hours ahead.

**Question**

How do I pass a date and time zone and get back a GMT timestamp with the correct offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parse function allows you to pass in the timezone

```
public static function parse($time = null, $tz = null)
```

So just pass it in:

```
$c = Carbon::parse($string, $time_zone);
```

Comment: I absolutely did NOT see that in the documentation. It works perfectly, this is going to save me so much stress! Thank you!

Comment: I didn't see it in the documentation either, but when it doubt, check the source code. Welcome!